# The number of questions tagged as [np-hardness]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The [tags page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags) says “[np-hardness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-hardness) × 70,” but the list of questions shows only 64.

Comment: Could it be because of deleted questions ?

Comment: @Suresh: Maybe, I do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the result of a moderator level tag rename.

These counts are automatically normalized every 24 hours so the problem is now gone.

Comment: Confirmed that the tags page shows the number of questions correctly.  Thank you for the explanation.